# How can I make this question of mine more clear?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, unclear

[How do I create a Block with custom layout or arrange for FlowDocuments?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56484682/3063273)

My question has so far gotten three close votes for lack of clarity. But I really thought my question was as clear as it can be. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask isn't very enlightening to me:

- My question comes at the end of lots of trial and error and searching how to accomplish something at my job where I spend lots of time embedded in WPF.
- I don't see how the title could be more clear.
- I introduced the problem in the most concise way I know how.
- It's not possible for me to give steps to reproduce something I cannot do.
- I don't see any additional applicable tags.
- I proof read it.
- I have responded to the (so far) sole comment (other than mine).

So here I am looking for help asking for help.

Comment: Too focused on the solution you had in mind, not focused enough on the problem you're trying to solve.  "You can't use a Block" would be a correct answer, but nobody can post it because it is not a solution.  A question that cannot produce a solution is not useful.

Comment: The question you should be asking: "How do I insert pagebreaks before a specific block in a FlowDocument?". Then it would be possible to answer with solutions on how to solve your problem. But you ask about how to do a specific (non-working) way to solve your actual problem.

Comment: @HansPassant That makes sense. Thanks, I'll keep that in mind next time.

Comment: @BDL I see what you mean. I suppose I didn't ask the question I should have because I already know the answers to that question (and I don't like them). Makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Of course if you were to ask how to solve the problem, your question would likely be downvoted to oblivion then closed and deleted because it wouldn't be a useless debugging question. Isn't it ironic?